# How to get content-desc in Android app using appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am writing automation test for Android app.

When I am trying to get content-desc for article title. I am not able to fetch it.

FYI I don't have text.

```
List<WebElement> arrayOfProperties2 = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.view.View");

for (WebElement property : arrayOfProperties2){
    System.out.println("property" + property.getClass());

    String contentDesc = property.getAttribute("name");
    String contentDesc1 = property.getAttribute("className");
    String contentDesc2 = property.getAttribute("resourceId");
    System.out.println("contentDesc" + contentDesc);
    System.out.println("contentDesc1" + contentDesc1);
    System.out.println("contentDesc2" + contentDesc2);
}
```

Result:-

```
contentDesc
contentDesc1android.view.View
contentDesc2
```

[image]

Comment: I assume that getAttribute("content-desc") and getAttribute("contentDesc") doesn't work (it shouldn't but...). I wish there was a way of retrieving all the attributes :)

Comment: @kiedysktos Can you tell me what it the way of doing it?

Comment: String contentDesc = property.getAttribute("content-desc");

Comment: @kiedysktos Its doesn't work for me and says as cannot find element.

Comment: I have no clue then...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Click to Resize']"));
webElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using it with UI automator2:

```
element.getAttribute(“contentDescription”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following appium docs http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/

Using `findElementByAccessibilityId` or `findElementsByAccessibilityId` you get:

> **Accessibility ID**
>
> Read a unique identifier for a UI element. For XCUITest it is the element's `accessibility-id` attribute. For Android it is the element's `content-desc` attribute.

Comment: I wouldn't agree to any of that ...while the XML layout is lacking resource ID. I mean, it would be so simple to handle, if not the XML had been produced in a manner that would pass no code review.