# How to use java to detect a bold font?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I want to make a automatic email responder for gmail.

The only way I can differentiate in between read and unread emails is that unread emails have a bold font.

[image: can't add images]

How would I write a program that can scan through the elements, detect if a given text is bold or not, and if it **IS** bold, click on that element?

Comment: Are you talking about JavaMail API? If so, search for the keyword Flag.SEEN. It would be helpful if you shared your current code instead of the picture.

Answer (score 2):

1. For mobile web browsers and /or WebViews you can use [WebElement.getCssValue()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue-java.lang.String-) function and look into [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) value which should be either `bold` or `700` for bold text
2. For native web applications you will not be able to play the same trick, if you're automating a native application it's better to stick to `Unread` text which should be in [content-desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268619/how-to-get-content-desc-in-android-app-using-appium) attribute:

   [image]

   If you go for this option you should be able to locate the "Unread" elements using [XPath contains() or starts-with() functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like

   ```
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Unread')]")).forEach(element -> ...);
   ```

   or

   ```
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.View[starts-with(@content-desc,'Unread')]")).forEach(element -> ...);
   ```

Comment: how do I use the forEach() function? what do i put inside the parenthesis?